# В каком виде и где хранить embed сообщения?

Tags: python, файлы, discord, disnake

У меня `embed` сообщения хранятся в коде в следующем виде:

````py
emb = disnake.Embed(description = '```hello world!```', colour = disnake.Color.blue()
````

хочу узнать лучший способ хранения `embed` сообщений вне кода и пример их вызова из какого либо файла. Были идеи делать это в `config.ini` или просто `txt` но вызов в коде у меня получался довольно громоздким.

Comment: @denisnumb а можно пример пожалуйста?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У всех объектов типа `discord.Embed` есть метод [**`to_dict()`**](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.Embed.to_dict), который преобразует класс в словарь. А полученный словарь можно затем преобразовать в JSON и сохранить в файл.

Пример:

```py
embed = discord.Embed(title='Заголовок', description='Описание', color=discord.Color.gold())
embed.add_field(name='Поле 1', value='Значение 1', inline=False)
embed.add_field(name='Поле 2', value='Значение 2', inline=True)

embed_data = embed.to_dict()
print(json.dumps(embed_data, indent=4, ensure_ascii=False))
```

Вывод:

```json
{
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "Поле 1",
            "value": "Значение 1",
            "inline": false
        },
        {
            "name": "Поле 2",
            "value": "Значение 2",
            "inline": true
        }
    ],
    "color": 15844367,
    "type": "rich",
    "description": "Описание",
    "title": "Заголовок"
}
```

И точно также обратно из словаря можно получить embed, при помощи метода класса [**`discord.Embed.from_dict()`**](https://docs.disnake.dev/en/stable/api.html#disnake.Embed.from_dict):

```py
embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_data)
```